# Why this piece of code is throwing classCastException

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
List<Object[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for(Object[] obj: arrayList)
{
  // assuming at 0th location Timestamp value 
  Date dt = convertTimestampToDate((Timestamp)obj[0]) // Timestampvalue , '2013-09-11 00:00:0' throwing classCastException at this line
}

public static java.sql.Date convertTimestampToDate(java.sql.Timestamp timestamp) {
        if(isNull(timestamp))
            return null;
        long milliseconds = timestamp.getTime() + (timestamp.getNanos() / 1000000);
        return new java.sql.Date(milliseconds);
    }
```

Exception thrown is

You cannot cast java.lang.String to Timestamp
Here, I am assuming obj[0] is an object type and casting it to Timestamp
Any Ideas will be appreciable.

Comment: How do you invoke the upper snippet ?

Comment: How are you populating `arrayList`?  Apparently `obj[0]` is a String.

Comment: @kocko Its a static method I ll be using ClassName.methodName

Answer (score 3):

The exception is pretty self explanatory.  In Java, everything is an Object (with the exception of primitives, but that's another subject).  So, even though you've got an array of `Object`s, that doesn't mean you can arbitrarily cast those `Objects` to anything you want.

```
Date dt = convertTimestampToDate((Timestamp)obj[0])
```

`obj[0]` is clearly a `String` when you attempt that cast, and as such you will need to use `SimpleDateFormat` or similar to parse that `String`.  You cannot cast a `String` to a `Timestamp` for the simple reason that Java doesn't (and can't) know how to do that.

Comment: obj[0] is clearly a String, will you pls clarify on this comment

Comment: You said your exception was `You cannot cast java.lang.String to Timestamp`
Therefore, the problem is that you're trying to cast a `String` to a `Timestamp`.  The only place in that code you're attempting to cast something to a `Timestamp` is `(Timestamp)obj[0]`.  Therefore, `obj[0]` is a `String`.  `String` is an `Object`.  `Timestamp` is an `Object`.  But a `String` is ***NOT*** a `Timestamp`, nor is a `Timestamp` a `String`.  Thus, you cannot simply **cast** one to the other, you have to **convert** the `String` to a `Timestamp`.

Comment: You can test if an object is of a given type using `instanceof`. `if(!obj[0] instanceof Timestamp){castToTimestamp(obj[0])}`

Comment: For that matter, come to think of it, you can do `System.out.println(obj[0].getClass())` so you can see for yourself what's going on

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the `String` object to `Timestamp` by using the [Timestamp#valueOf(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Change

```
Date dt = convertTimestampToDate((Timestamp)obj[0]) ;
```

to

```
Date dt = convertTimestampToDate(Timestamp.valueOf(obj[0].toString()));
```

Comment: Here, obj[0] is of type Object so, toString() need to invoked.

Comment: Thank you @kocko Now its giving the desired output.